# Only allow access to a php action through form submit, but when using an ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

i have a form that deletes the comment its in.

To only allow the page that carries out the php action to be viewed when the form is submitted i do a basic

```
if (isset($_POST['submit-delete'])) {
     // carry out delete
}
```

this works fine, but i am using ajax to not reload the page.

The response is the same as i have used else where:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".delrepcomment").submit(function(){

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "process/deletecomment.php",
data: $(".delrepcomment").serialize(),
dataType: "json",
success: function(response){
    if (response.commentDeleted === true) {
        $('#successdisplay').fadeIn(1000),
        $('#successdisplay').delay(2500).fadeOut(400);
    }
    else {
        $('.delrepcomment').after('<div class="error">Something went wrong!</div>');
    }
}
});
    return false;
    });
});
```

This however doesnt work, unless i remove the check to see if the form has been submitted.

Whats the best way around this? I want to keep the check for the form being submitted incase of js being turned off or any direct access attempts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post the data you require for the script to work. In your case, you have to post a key-value-pair with "submit-delete" as the key and an arbitrary value (unless you check that value later in the code).

On the other hand, PHP stores the used HTTP method in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`, this would be "POST" in your case.